# Alternative to direct inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I have two classes **class A** and **class B**. I want **class B** to have functionality of **class A** plus some more functionality of its own. One of the very simple ways to do this is to inherit **class B** from **class A**. But I cannot do this for some implementation specific reasons.

I have thought of another solution where in I will create another class **class C** which will contain all the virtual functions. The **classes A and B** will inherit from **class C**. The **class A** will contain the implementation of virtual functions and **class B** can also define the same set of functions and hence **class B** will have functionality of **class A**.
Is this the optimal solution? Are there any better solutions than this other than direct inheriting **class B** from **class A**?

Comment: *"But I cannot do this for some implementation specific reasons"* is not a good but often (ab)used excuse for bad designs. If your design demands Inheritance use it and if some implementation prevents you from doing so, change it.

Comment: What are the "implementation specific reasons"?

Comment: If you have control over what both A and B inherit from (and you must by the proposal of you C-->A, C-->B solution) I fail to see why you suddenly *lack* that control to simply let A-->B and be done with it.

Answer (score 11):

What you are looking for is called [**Composition** (over Inheritance)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

> Composition over inheritance (or Composite Reuse Principle) in
>   object-oriented programming is a technique by which classes may
>   achieve polymorphic behavior and code reuse by containing other
>   classes that implement the desired functionality instead of through
>   inheritance.

This means that instead of having `class B` inherit from `class A`, you can have `class B` contain an instance of `class A`. This is also **good coding practice** to avoid tight coupling between `class A` and `class B`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that however if you create `class C` to be an abstract base class and have class A and class B inheriting from it, then you realize that `class A` and `class B` would be unrelated except for the fact that they inherit from the same abstract base class. That means that you would not be able to cast instances of `class B` to `A`, etc. In general such implementation depends on the use cases.

E.g.:

Your `class C` is `Person`, `class A` is `Teacher` and `class B` is `Student`. Then a student is not a teacher and a teacher is not a student, so such implementation is valid.

Comment: If class C is not an abstract class and if there is some default functionality provided in class C then both class A and class B will share the functionality of class C.

Answer (score 0):

> The class A will contain the implementation of virtual functions and class B can also define the same set of functions

This way you'll have code-duplication and it's not a good thing.

If you don't want to use inheritance, try composition.

I explained composition earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12972995/how-a-class-can-extend-with-two-different-classes-while-one-class-is-from-a-exte/12973079#12973079).

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy classes, by creating two other classes `PA` and `PB` where `PB` inherits from `PA`. These proxy classes duplicate the *interfaces* of `A` and `B` respectively, but don't actually *implement* them. Instead, they just call the functions in an instance of `A` and `B`.